# How to read in a fixed column width file with headers every 3rd row

Tags: r, fixed-width

I have a fixed column width file with headers (that contain important information) every 5th row. Like this:

```
XX ZZ MM
1 12 5 22 9 12 13 11 17 21
2 12 6 22 10 12 14 11 18 21
3 12 7 22 11 12 15 11 19 21
4 12 8 22 12 12 16 11 20 21
AA BB CC
1 12 5 12 9 11 13 21 17 21
2 12 6 22 10 12 14 11 18 21
3 12 7 22 11 12 15 11 19 21
4 12 8 22 12 12 16 11 20 21
```

First, I'd like to be able to read the file in.  I've had some success with `laf_open_fwf` in the `laf` package.
But, when I used this function I lose either the header info or the data depending on where I set the fixed column widths.

The data are organized in columns so that the odd columns(first, third, fifth, seventh, and ninth) are ID numbers and the even columns are the actual data.

What I'd like to end up with is something that looks like this:

```
XX ZZ MM 1 12
XX ZZ MM 2 12
XX ZZ MM 3 12
XX ZZ MM 4 12
XX ZZ MM 5 22
XX ZZ MM 6 22
XX ZZ MM 7 22
XX ZZ MM 8 22
XX ZZ MM 9 12
XX ZZ MM 10 12
XX ZZ MM 11 12
XX ZZ MM 12 12
XX ZZ MM 13 11
XX ZZ MM 14 11
XX ZZ MM 15 11
XX ZZ MM 16 11
XX ZZ MM 17 21
XX ZZ MM 18 21
XX ZZ MM 19 21
XX ZZ MM 20 21
XX ZZ MM 21 21
AA BB CC 1 12
AA BB CC 2 12
AA BB CC 3 12
AA BB CC 4 12
AA BB CC 5 22
AA BB CC 6 22
AA BB CC 7 22
AA BB CC 8 22
AA BB CC 9 12
AA BB CC 10 12
AA BB CC 11 12
AA BB CC 12 12
AA BB CC 13 11
AA BB CC 14 11
AA BB CC 15 11
AA BB CC 16 11
AA BB CC 17 21
AA BB CC 18 21
AA BB CC 19 21
AA BB CC 20 21
AA BB CC 21 21
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you mean that every 5th row there's a header? Or is it best to assume that any row that doesn't start with a number is a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read in the file, iterate through lines, and test whether each line is a header. If it's not a header line, then print out the latest header we've seen as well as two data values at a time. It would look something like this:

```
text <- readLines('/path/to/file')                   # read in the file
split_text <- strsplit(text, "\\s+")                 # split each line on whitespace

for (line in split_text) {                           # iterate through lines
  numeric_line <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(line)) # try to convert the current line into a vector of numbers
  if (is.na(numeric_line[[1]])) {                    # if it fails, we know we're on a header line
    header <- line
  } else {
    for (i in seq(1, length(line), 2)) {             # otherwise, we're on a data line, so take two numbers at once
      print(c(header, line[[i]], line[[i+1]]))       # and output the latest header with each pair of values
    }
  }
}
```

This just prints to standard output, since no particular output was specified. Note that the order of the output isn't exactly the same as the example you showed – if you want it in that order, you'll have to store the output first and then sort it.